# c++ Forward Declaration design

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, forward

From what i've read, i should use forward declarations whenever I can. I have classes like this ( where every fields are pointers because of forward declarations ) :

```
class A
{
    // ...

    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
    D* d;
    E* e;
};
```

But there is problems with that.

1- This implies to call new and delete ( or at least new with smart pointers ) for every fields in constructor, while stack allocated fields don't need this.

2- I've read that stack allocation was faster than heap allocation.

3- Also that means that almost every fields on every classes should be pointers.

Am I doing the right way doing like my example class? Or am I missing something with forward declarations?

Comment: Side note: in case of `A* a;` you have no other chance then use pointer, because A cannot keep A - it would create infinity dependency resulting in A's size being infinite.

Comment: Qt uses this all the time. They claim that it doesn't matter because most code is not performance critical anyway.

Comment: @Laethnes: True sorry, that was just an example.

Comment: @sashoalm Yeah, that's true and I'm all the time wondering how it performs on smaller devices :3.

Comment: @Aulaulz No need to apologize, I just wanted to clarify that also for potential future readers.

Comment: +1 Looking at the answers so far, convinced me this is a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you've shown is an overkill. The suggestion to use forward declarations doesn't mean your code design is driven by forward declaration practices. Forward declarations are just implementation detail, the design prevails.

First decide whether you need aggregation or composition, then whether the forward declaration is appropriate.

**Do** prefer forward declaration over `#include` when the forward-declared type is part of your method signature, i.e. a parameter's type.

```
#include "OtherClass.h" // 'bad' practice

class OtherClass; // this is better than #include
....
class MyClass
{
    void method(OtherClass *ptr);
}
```

It's not an absolute rule anyway as it's not always possible/convenient to use forward decls instead of includes.

Comment: This. Plus read something about premature optimization - the forward declaration is suggested so the compilation time is shorter and in order to avoid re-compilation of lots of files when header changes. But as usual, this is IMHO one of these things which should be optimized when problem arose, not before. My own example: my personal library hit this problem, solution was simple: precompiled headers. And I didn't need to take care of lots of pointers during development :).

Comment: @Laethnes absolutely. The syntactic details are easy to get, the **big problems** follow years later.

Comment: I found a little (Freudian?) typo: `froward` ;)

Answer (score 7):

The implication is inverse - you're not supposed to use pointers just in order to use forward declarations, but you're suppose to use forward declarations after you've taken a design decision (such as using pointers instead of objects as members) when you can.

So if it makes more sense to use objects, do so, and include the files you need. Don't use pointers just so you can forward-declare the classes.

Comment: You wrote `or objects as members` - is this really possible with forward declaration?

Comment: @Wolf no. Precisely what I meant - don't take a design decision based on whether or not you can use forward declarations. If you need objects as members, do it and include the files you need.

Comment: Then, `instead of` would be a little bit less confusing for this answer (of course, I understand what you mean).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using pointers as members, prefer forward declaration than exposing complete class definition. Don't use pointers just to meet some rule blindly.

Answer (score 2):

Technically spoken, you can (and should!) use a forward declaration, **if the interface of your class doesn't depend on a fully qualified type**. The compiler has to reserve enough space for members and add management functions at compile time - just using pointers or references in your class does not introduce dependencies on types.

*BTW: Forward declaration isn't that new: In some C standard libraries, `FILE` is a `typedef` for a forward declared `struct`, which makes sense since `FILE` is always used for pointers in the whole public file API.*

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers or references for objects that the class doesn't own. But for objects that are owned by this class don't use forward declarations as a reason for choosing pointers.

If you really want to minimize compile time dependencies consider the PIMPL idom rather than turning all your members into pointers:

MyClass.h:

```
#include <memory>
class MyClassImpl;

class MyClass {
 public:
   MyClass();
  ~MyClass();
   void doThing();
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<MyClassImpl> pimpl_;
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyClassImpl.h"

MyClass::MyClass() { } // in .cpp so unique_ptr constructor has complete type

MyClass::~MyClass() { } // in .cpp so unique_ptr destructor has complete type

void MyClass::doThing(){
  pimpl_->doThing();
}
```

MyClassImpl.h:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

class MyClassImpl {
 private:
  A a_;
  B b_;
 public:
  void doThing();
};
```

MyClassImpl.cpp:

```
#include "MyClassImpl.h"

void MyClassImpl::doThing() {
  // Do stuff with a_, b_, etc...
}
```

This might not address performance concerns as you still have dynamic memory allocation but you would have to measure it to see.

Comment: Did Aulaulz mention this?

Comment: @Wolf: minimising compile time dependencies is the main reason for using forward declarations, so indirectly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers already given: In cases where your class doesn't create an object but uses it *privately* (for instance some utility class), references can be used instead of pointers.

```
class UtilityClass; // forward declaration (even interfaces make sense here)

class MyClass {
public:
    /// takes an UtilityClass for implementing some of its functions
    MyClass(UtilityClass& u): util(u) {}
private:
    UtilityClass& util;
    // ...more details
};
```

These are cases, where forward declaration doesn't mean that objects have to be created on heap (as for your problems #1 and #2).